# Exclude activity from recents menu by code

Tags: android

I need to exclude an activity from appearing in recent launched menu, but i am not able of adding `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, I have to do it in runtime.

Does anyone knows if there is possible to set `FLAG_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS` to the activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to achieve this via code is to set the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS`  in the intent that launches the activity.