# Can i disable recentappbutton android 4.0 programmatically?

Tags: android

I am developing a project and i need disable recent app button.

Can anybody know if it is possible?If i can do,how can i do that?

THX.

Comment: You can't disable system features like that. You can exclude your app from recents http://stackoverflow.com/q/1236187/995891

Comment: Solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12652490/1555824