# Remove recent app button as done in SureLock application

Tags: android, android-intent

Dose any one have any idea on how is sure lock removing recent app button from navigation bar on an unrooted device or is there any way by which we can disable home and recent app icon.

Any reply would be of great help...

thanks,
Ankit

Comment: Can you post some pictures for illustration

Comment: hello @AnkitAggarwal have you got the solution, i have to disable navigation bar in my app, if this is not possible so how can i disable recent apps button ?

Answer (score 2):

What [SureLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gears42.surelock) does is add the flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS) in the intent passed to [startActivity(intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29). See an earlier discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13385366/925202).

Answer (score 0):

By making your app the launcher app, it disables the home button.  I am not sure how to disable the recent apps button yet.. I will look for that