# removing application from recents in android 4.2.2

Tags: android

I want to remove app from the recents. I have used android:excludeFromRecents="true" in manifest file.

So, whenever i click on home button, app is not present in recent list.
But when i open app, and click on recents, app will be part of recent apps list and it is accessible.

Is there any way to remove (or restrict app being part of recents) app when user click on recent when app was open.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385289/remove-app-from-recent-apps-programmatically