# Application should not display in recent app list after finish the activity if app was not displaying recent app list previously

Tags: android, android-activity, twilio

Step 1- Application is not exist in recent app list (App has been removed from recent app list).
Step 2- As soon as I got notification open [IncomingCall](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client/incoming-connections) activity, User accept the call.
Step 3- User click on disconnect button finish the IncomingCall activity.

Problem- Application showing in recent app list even app was not in recent app list previously.

Manifest entry

```
<activity
android:name=".activities.IncomingCall"
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

In the activity using

```
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.onCallDisconnectButton:
phoneCallBaseClass.disconnect();
IncomingCall.this.finish();
break;
  }
}
```

And also I have tried below link but it will work when app already exist in background

[Remove app from recent apps programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385289/remove-app-from-recent-apps-programmatically)

OR
Is there any other way to show incoming call view So that it will not persist in history.

you can take example of any VoIP calls app-

Remove app from recent app list after that incoming call came, user disconnect the call activity(IncomingCallActivity) would not be exist in recent app list.
But in My case activity persist in recent app list after disconnecting the call.

Thanks

Comment: try using `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`

Comment: I have tried still showing in recent app list

Comment: is this the activity that you are opening from notification

Comment: Yes Mentioned in question Incoming call actiivity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks God, I got answer after wondering a week.
Add singleInstance attribute along with exclude from recent.
It was a bug in 5.0 now has been resolved in 5.1

```
 <activity
        android:name="activityName"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
         >
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 11):

Add

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

to the activity tag of your launcher activity in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true">
....
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks but already I have followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385289/remove-app-from-recent-apps-programmatically

Comment: Awesome, I didnt know it.

Answer (score 4):

As per you needs, [finishAndRemoveTask()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.AppTask.html#finishAndRemoveTask()) is the new API that as per the documentation

> Finishes all activities in this task and removes it from the recent
>   tasks list.

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
{
    finishAndRemoveTask();
}
else
{
    finish();
}
```