# Cordova app still shown in task viewer after exit on Galaxy s3

Tags: android, cordova, galaxy

When I try to exit the app with `navigator.app.exitApp();` the app exits succesfully. But when I go to the task overview (with long pressing the home button) on my Galaxy s3, it still shows the last page that I was on when the app was on.

It works properly, because when I launch the app again from the task overview, it launches the app again as cold start. The problem is that the task overview reveals confidential information and I do not want that.

The work around that I have now is that the app first navigates to another page, without confidential information, just before calling `navigator.app.exitApp();`. However this results in a quick navigation between screens, and gives a bad user experience.

Is there any way to remove the app from the task overview when exiting the app in Cordova, or is this just how Samsung or the Galaxy series works?

Comment: Would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13385366/1744702) help?

Comment: Good link, though I was hoping for a solution in Cordova and that it would only get removed from the recent apps list when it was not running anymore

Comment: It's how android works, all the apps I use (phonegap and native) appear on the recent apps even if I quit them

Comment: Then there is probably no other solution than removing the app from the recent apps view with the solution given by @sanfor. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a summary answer of comments provided:

According to jcesarmobile, there is no way to remove them from the apps list programmatically even if quit.

There seems, though, to be possibility to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385289/remove-app-from-recent-apps-programmatically/13385366#13385366) to exclude it from the recent apps in the first place.