# Exclude from recent apps list for Android 4.4.2 only

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, programmatically-created, android-recents

I would like to exclude my app from the recent apps list (long press home, multitasking button, etc) BUT only for Android 4.4.1 and 4.4.2. The reason being is that on these Android versions, services can't restart themselves and my service is killed when my app is swiped away from the recents list. Normally it restarts itself without a problem, but it can't do so on 4.4.1 and 4.4.2.

I know you can add android:excludeFromRecents="true" in the manifest but that will exclude it on all Android versions.

I tried what was suggested here but can't get it to work:

[Remove app from recent apps programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385289/remove-app-from-recent-apps-programmatically)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude yourself from the recent-tasks list on 4.4 (not only 4.4.2):

Step #1: Create `res/values/bools.xml` with a `bool` resource, named `is_44`, set to `false`

Step #2: Create `res/values-v19/bools.xml` with a `bool` resource, named `is_44`, set to `true`

Step #3: Create `res/values-v21/bools.xml` with a `bool`, named `is_44`, set to `false`

Step #4: Use `android:excludeFromRecents="@bool/is_44"` in your `<activity>`

So, for API Level 19 and 20, you will be excluded from recents, but not other API levels.

Comment: Although this does not specifically target 4.4.2 it is good enough for me, so I will be selecting it as the correct answer. I guess there is no way to do this programmatically  once we know the exact build version? Also, I think you mixed up the bool values, wouldn't you want it to be true for v19?

Comment: @Flyview: "I guess there is no way to do this programmatically once we know the exact build version?" -- I don't think so. "Also, I think you mixed up the bool values, wouldn't you want it to be true for v19?" -- no, I think I have it right. `is_not_44` should be `false` for 19 and 20 (Android 4.4/4.4W) and `true` for everything else.

Comment: But then android:excludeFromRecents becomes false for v19 and v20! Don't we want this true so that the app is excluded from the recent apps list?

Comment: Also I noticed that while this approach does work to remove the app from recents list for 4.4.x, the app still shows up in the recents list if accessing opening the list with the activity still in the foreground. This still allows the user to swipe it away and thereby kill the service forever.

Comment: @Flyview: ::sigh:: I think I got confused by a triple-negative. `is_44` will be `true` for 19 and 20 and therefore you will be excluded from recents for those. "the app still shows up in the recents list if accessing opening the list with the activity still in the foreground" -- I am not aware of any way of affecting that behavior.

Comment: Perfect, I had already used is_44. Thanks for editing your answer! You're something of a stackoverflow celebrity. :)

Answer (score 1):

If Android *4.4.x* is exact enough you could create a folder `layout-v19` and define an extra layout for the activity, which should be excluded from the recent apps list:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".anActivity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    ...>
```

See [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) documentation (search for *Platform Version*) and API levels [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Comment: This would probably work, but the answer by CommonsWare is more elegant. Thanks!