# removing activity from Task manager stack in android

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, activity-lifecycle, android-recents

I am working on and **Android** application. When my application is running and i press the recent applications button on the phone , Activity's **onPause()** method is called . Inside this **onPause** i call **finish()** . So the activity gets destroyed.

But its still visible in the recent applications list.

How do i make sure it is not listed in the recent applications list when i destroy my activity from **onPause()**.

Comment: Why would you want to explicitly finish your app when the user puts it in the background? That's terrible.

Answer (score 10):

Try doing

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true" ...>
```

**in your AndroidManifest.xml's activity declaration.**

get more from [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

> Whether or not the task initiated by this activity should be excluded
>   from the list of recently used applications ("recent apps"). That is,
>   when this activity is the root activity of a new task, this attribute
>   determines whether the task should not appear in the list of recent
>   apps. Set "true" if the task should be excluded from the list; set
>   "false" if it should be included. The default value is "false".

when you want to have special properties for an Activity when starting it you supply special flags to the Intent. In this case FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS.

Go through [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385289/remove-app-from-recent-apps-programmatically).

Comment: i have tried with small example,yours working perfectly.I have not tried scenario basis.

Answer (score 2):

use finishAndRemoveTask() instead of finish() or finishAffinity()

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be because only your activity is destroyed not the Application instance. Android awaits may be user open up the app again.
To completely terminate application you can use
for above API 16  `this.finishAffinity()` .

It will finish the current activity and all other under it. As doc says

> Finish this activity as well as all activities immediately below it in
>   the current task that have the same affinity

Comment: yours is not working, still recent is retained the app

Answer (score 0):

use

```
finish();
```

when you move to the next activity then recent activity is finish