# Not able to open Splash after exit the application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I am working on an application in which I want to exit the app `onBackPressed`. I have wrote code for it but the problem is this when I press back button my app exits and not cleared from RAM and when I reopen the app after exit it opens from second screen not from splash. What is the problem?

Code:

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
finish();
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385289/remove-app-from-recent-apps-programmatically

Comment: Please provide the main activity and splash screen codes

Answer (score 0):

Best way of handle splash screen is clear splash stack from Intent. So you don't need to kill your application manually

```
Intent intent = new Intent(splashActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Don't forgot to remove below code

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
finish();
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in onCreate() splash screen activity .

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                            intent = new Intent(ActivitySplachScreen.this, MainActivity.class);  
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                }
            }, 3000);
        }
```

& activity_splash_screen is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```