# Remove from the recent list only when the activity finished

Tags: android

First of all, this method

```
android:noHistory="true"
android:taskAffinity=""
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

is not what I want, because when activity is running, the user clicks the home button, and the activity can no longer return to the previous state.
is there another way to set it in running,  remove it from the recent list when the user clicks.

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13385366/8738231

Comment: I have test it by pixel，doesn't work