# How to set foreground application as not showing in recent list?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recents

I know how to remove an application or activity from recent list by adding `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` to Manifest file.
This will remove the activities when they are not in the foreground.

I tried adding the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` also. But, no activities on the foreground can be hidden from recent list when the home button is long pressed during that time.
My activity gets killed when swiped away from the recent list, while it is in the foreground.
How to remove the foreground activity or a whole foreground application from Recent list?

Comment: Are you saying if an app is in foreground and you hit recent apps you don't want it to appear in the recents?

Comment: @sanjeev exactly..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove app from recent apps programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385289/remove-app-from-recent-apps-programmatically)

Comment: @ManojPerumarath Nop..Bcoz, it says abt removing it through code. What I want is to hide foreground activity from recents by any means.

Comment: @ManojPerumarath I ve gone through all those solutions, but nthng work to hide a foreground app

Comment: I am testing on Samsung A10 (API 28) , in my project, minSdkVersion 21 and targetSdkVersion 29.

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".CallActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"/> 

this is in my manifest declaration. And,

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

 is also called while starting the activity.

Comment: @AmeenaShafeer As I checked it, adding `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` to your launcher activity in manifest removes the whole app from recent app's list even when the app is running, in Android 7.0 only. In Android 8.0 and above, I think OS doesn't allow the app / activity to be removed from recent / running apps' list.

minSdkVersion: 23
targetSdkVersion: 28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "hide" your application from the user this way. Tasks with running activities are always displayed in the list of recent tasks.

The only way to remove your task from the list of recent tasks is to set `android:noHistory="true"` on all `<activity>` declarations in the manifest. However, this will cause the activities to be finished when the user navigates away from them (ie: presses the HOME button or the "recents" button, so this is probably not what you want.